XM Cloud Page Editor encountered an error: Unable to connect to your rendering host at http://rendering:3000/api/editing/render
While utilizing the XM Cloud Page Editor, I encountered an error related to the rendering host. Upon investigating the docker container logs associated with the rendering host, I observed several errors, notably:
Error: Image with src "/sitecore/shell/Themes/Standard/Images/WebEdit/default_image.svg?iar=0" is missing required "width" property.

After engaging in discussions within the Sitecore Slack channels, I learned that this issue might be related to component rendering. I would appreciate it if anyone who has encountered a similar issue could kindly share the steps they took to resolve it. Thank you.


Does this problem occur after adding or creating a new component?

No, it was working fine, The issue was resolved by initiating a refresh of the local cache
